# nodeMCU connect refused with XMAPP localhost

Tags: xampp, arduino-esp8266

My project is about using nodeMCU measure value from sensor DHT11 and sent value to database Mysql. I use xampp for server. I cannot sent value to database.
nodeMCU can read value and sent value.But HTTP GET is fail.And return connect refused. I think maybe have problems with port for listening.

this is my code

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 2 // what digital pin the DHT22 is conected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT11 // there are multiple kinds of DHT sensors

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
const char* ssid = "something";
const char* password = "something";

int EP =5;

void setup() {

Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(EP, INPUT);
for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
Serial.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
Serial.flush();
delay(1000);
}
WiFiMulti.addAP(ssid, password); // ssid , password
randomSeed(50);
}

int timeSinceLastRead = 0;

void loop() {
if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
HTTPClient http;
float temp = dht.readTemperature();
float humi = dht.readHumidity();
long meas =TP_init();
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

//int temp = random(25,35);
String url = "localhost:8012/add2.php?temp="+String(temp)+"&humi="+String(humi)+"&meas=0";

Serial.println(url);
http.begin(url); //HTTP

int httpCode = http.GET();
if (httpCode > 0) {
Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
String payload = http.getString();
Serial.println(payload);
}
} else {
Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
}
http.end();
}
delay(3000);
}

long TP_init(){
delay(10);
long meas=pulseIn (EP, HIGH); //wait for the pin to get HIGH and returns measurement
return meas;
}
```

- I changed Apache port from 80 to 8012
- I use PHPMyadmin for store database . File php's name add2.php for insert value from sensor DHT11

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVUj1.png)

This is result from serial port.

Comment: Could you add the error as part of the question so in case in the future the image is no longer available we can still know the error? Thanks!

Comment: And where do you think localhost points to?

Comment: @c-preaw Are you still stuck with this?

Answer (score 1):

`String url = "localhost` should be replaced with `String url = "<IP-address-of-your-webserver>` as the webserver clearly isn't running on the ESP8266.